# SQL recursive join with window function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently trying to run a simulation in SQL, the query is to monitor cost against a pre-defined target.

The amount being monitored is a 91 day moving average cost so this uses a correlated sub query to get the correct amount, but on days when the performance target is breached, the amount is adjusted to the target. (if moving average is 110, the monitor for this day from next day forward will take 100 instead of 110 as the payment would have been reduced on this day.)

Example, want to measure on what days costs breach a target of say 100, the costs are monitored on a 91 day moving average. When the target is breached there is a reduction in payment and the amount included in the monitor is adjusted to the target. I have been able to implement this but now I need to adjust for 91 days moving instead of the beginning of the time period. This would be possible if I could have 2 recursive queries but I don't believe this is possible. I have also tried various joining methods but they all become circular.

Any suggested approach would be greatly appreciated.
[image: Sample data table]

Comment: It would be a good idea to share the existing table structure you have and an illustration of the current way the data is calculated and also the expected way

Comment: Sample data and expected result. A [very few] rows of data will help us a lot to understand what you need.

Comment: Thank you, I have added a sample dataset, so within Amount rolling average column (10 day rolling for example), I want to measure when amount goes above target and then that day will be flagged. Additional to this, when monitoring the following day I want to adjust the rolling average by the reduction to target for the previous day when target was breached. So in above example the row with 100.1 would be flagged and then the next day it would use 100 instead of 115, this would mean that 101.4 moving average reduced to 99.9 and is below target.